# printing text in java textarea automatically from other textarea

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I'm developing a small application using Java Swing. It consist of 2 textareas. While typing the text in one textarea I want the same text to be copied on other textarea.
I've used threads: thread1 for Jframe and thread2 which access the text and `setText` in other textarea.. but text is not displaying.

Comment: No need to go with threads, try action listeners on the jtextarea like inputMethodTextChanged etc, try to a little research on them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you used any action listener to detect when the user types in the text box?

Comment: i dont know how to use that.. im newbie. can u explain me in detail

Comment: Check this out, its a good explanation

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html

If this answer was useful, please mark it as answered.

Comment: yep i understood how to use action listner.. but how can i invoke this while text change

Comment: i got it..! i searched for InputMethodTextChange... if any one have d same problem find out here >> http://jan.newmarch.name/i18n/input/input.html thanq Ravi for ur reply.. :)

Answer (score 1):

> I want the same text to be copied on other textarea

Share the Document:

```
JTextArea textArea1 = new JTextArea();
JTextArea textArea2 = new JTextArea();
textArea2.setDocument( textArea1.getDocument() );
```